# Application bundles uploaded using Google Developer API do not appear anywhere, despite successful request execution

Tags: python, android, google-api, google-play-console

Here is the Python code I am using, building on the `googleapiclient` module:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build, MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

app_id = "com.myapp.myapp.app"
aab_file_path = "H:/packages/0.0.18/com.myapp.myapp.app.aab"
service_account_file_path = "service-account-key.json"

# Create the service account credentials object.
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    service_account_file_path, ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher"]
)

# Create the API client object.
service = build("androidpublisher", "v3", credentials=credentials)

# Get an edit ID.
request = service.edits().insert(packageName=app_id)
response = request.execute()
editId = response['id']

media_body = MediaFileUpload(aab_file_path, mimetype='application/octet-stream', resumable=True)
request = service.edits().bundles().upload(
    packageName=app_id,
    editId=editId,
    media_body=media_body,
)
response = request.execute()

# Check that the response contains a versionCode.
versionCode = response.get("versionCode")
if response.get("versionCode") is not None:
  print("Bundle successfully uploaded.")
else:
  print("Failed to upload bundle.")
```

The script runs through, the `versionCode` retrieved is correct, but the bundle is not actually visible in the `App bundle explorer` in the Google Play Console, neither is it useable to update a track, or returned by `edits.bundles.list`.

Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [some help from the Play Console Help platform](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/228934140/application-bundles-uploaded-using-google-developer-api-do-not-appear-anywhere-despite-successful-r), I solved this. It turns out I was not committing the bundle edit like this:

```
  request = service.edits().commit(editId=editId, packageName=app_id)
  response = request.execute()
```

Somehow I was convinced that I had tried that and it was telling me the edit was already committed, but I must have dreamt it.